# Modular option for tikz lecture heading

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, table-of-contents, graphics, sectioning

I have a setup I use for lectures, for some lectures how would I be able to leave the date section empty and have the frame be built completely and not have a gap in the top. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\newcommand{\lec}[3]{
      \setcounter{chapter}{#1 - 1}
      \date{#2}
      \chapter[#3 - #2]{#3}
    }
```

```
    \let\Date\@date
    \def\chaptername{Lecture}
    \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, inner ysep=.3cm, color = RoyalPurple] (title) {\parbox{\dimexpr        \textwidth-.667em}{\centering \textcolor{black}{\textbf       {\Large\chaptername~\thechapter}\\
      \textit{#1}}}};
    \node[fill=white, right=2pt] at (title.north west)        {\footnotesize\@date};
    \end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
    }
    \makeatother
    
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, inner ysep=.3cm, color = RoyalPurple] (title) {\parbox{\dimexpr        \textwidth-.667em-0.4pt}{\centering \textcolor{black}{
            \textit{\large #1}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
    }
    \makeatother
```

[image]

Basically, I'd like to be able to leave the date portion of my lec command empty and have the frame be built completely when I do.

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\lec}[3]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{#1 - 1}
    \date{#2}
    \chapter[#3 - #2]{#3}
  }


  \makeatletter
  \let\Date\@date
  \def\chaptername{Lecture}
  \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, inner ysep=.3cm, color = RoyalPurple] (title) {\parbox{\dimexpr        \textwidth-.667em}{\centering \textcolor{black}{\textbf       {\Large\chaptername~\thechapter}\\
    \textit{#1}}}};
  \node[fill=white, right=2pt] at (title.north west)        {\footnotesize\@date};
  \end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
  }
  \makeatother
  
  \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, inner ysep=.3cm, color = RoyalPurple] (title) {\parbox{\dimexpr        \textwidth-.667em-0.4pt}{\centering \textcolor{black}{
          \textit{\large #1}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
  }
  \makeatother

\begin{document}
    \lec{1}{6/2/13}{test}
    \lec{2}{}{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could post something that compiles and shows your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Just added a working example by piecing together some code from my package hopefully that helps

Comment: Thank you, this really helps a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably make use of the `titlesec` pacakge and do something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\def\chaptername{Lecture}
\def\chapterdate{}
        
\NewDocumentCommand{\chaptertitlebox}{ m m }{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, inner sep=.3cm, draw=RoyalPurple, text width={\textwidth-2\pgflinewidth-.6cm}, align=center] (title) 
            {\textbf{\Large\chaptername~\thechapter} \\ \textit{#2}};
        \pgfmathparse{int(width{"#1"})}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\else
                \node[fill=white, right=2pt] at (title.north west)
                    {\footnotesize #1};
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{}{}{0pt}{\chaptertitlebox{\chapterdate}{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lecture}{ O{} m }{
    \begingroup
        \def\chapterdate{#1}
        \chapter{#2}
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

    \lecture[21 June 2023]{The first lecture}
    
    Foo

    \lecture{The second lecture}

    Foo
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Or change the definition to

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\lecture}{ m O{} m }{
    \begingroup
        \setcounter{chapter}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}
        \def\chapterdate{#2}
        \chapter[#3 -- #2]{#3}
    \endgroup
}
```

If you want to explicity state the lecture number and keep the date in the bookmark. To be used like this: `\lecture{1}[21 June 2023]{The first lecture}`.

There are probably several ways to check whether the token is empty or not. Here, I just measure the width of it contents. More concretely, I test whether the width of a box that contains the text stored in the token is zero, which would mean that it is empty.

---

If you want to stick to your approach, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\lec}[3]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}
    \gdef\chapterdate{#2}
    \chapter[#3 - #2]{#3}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\chaptername{Lecture}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, inner sep=.3cm, draw=RoyalPurple, text width={\textwidth-2\pgflinewidth-.6cm}, align=center] (title) 
            {\textbf{\Large\chaptername~\thechapter} \\ \textit{#1}};
        \pgfmathparse{int(width{"\chapterdate"})}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\else
            \node[fill=white, right=2pt] at (title.north west)
                {\footnotesize\chapterdate};
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \lec{1}{6/2/13}{test}
    \lec{2}{}{test}
\end{document}
```

Note the following:

- For `\setcounter{chapter}{#1-1}` to work, you need to load the `calc` package. Otherwise you need to say `\setcounter{chapter}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}` as shown in my example.
- I would not (ab)use the `\date` command here. You can just define you own token variable for storing the date for the chapter title. You never know which package might want to access the value stored in `\@date`, so it is better not to overwrite it. Apart from that, you never use `\Date`, so you can actually delete `\let\Date\@date`.
- You've got two `\makeatother` but only one `\makeatletter` in your code.
- You'd rather use `\usepackage` than `\RequirePackage` in a user document. The latter is made for code in pacakges or document classes.

Comment: Ive tried implementing your code into my package and it bricks the whole document and errors, is there a way to use what I originally had without titlesec?

Comment: @xyz04 Yes, but it would be more difficult. What errors do you get?

Comment: Well i put it into my preamble and after using the command it puts "[21 June 2023]The first lecture" below the lecture header box

Comment: @xyz04 You need to use the right syntax with the corresponding defintion and you need to load the right packages. I added another approach that does not use `titlesec`.

Comment: Looks like this has done the job, thanks!